# Help migrating from joomla to wordpress

Tags: contextual-help

Greetings I hope are well, I have a problem migrating my joomla site to wordpress 3.3 4. 
these are the steps I did:

1- uploaded the wordpress to the server where I have the web with joomla

2 create a database for wordpress

3  install plugins FG joomla wordpres and to fill the data. 
but when I try to connect from the plugins before doing the migration I get this error: 
"[fgj2wp] PDO is required. Please enable it."

I must say that I am new to wordpress, I hope someone can give their opinion is welcome. greetings.

Comment: [PDO is a PHP extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). It must be enabled on your server.

Answer (score 3):

Go to php.ini file and search "extension=pdo_mysql.so" in commented line. Just uncomment that line and you will get success.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.